# Debian container doesn't - Docker Desktop on Windows 11

Tags: windows, docker

I have installed the latest Docker Desktop on a Windows 11. My intention was to run a Debian container but it does not start.

I have pull the `debian:bookworm-slim` image, I am starting a new container:

```
docker run --name test_debian -d debian:bookworm-slim
```

but it stops immediately. What's even weirder is that there is nothing in the log.

What else could I test or configure?

Comment: Checkout disk size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the exepected behavior, since the [default command](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/debian/bookworm-slim/images/sha256-36a9d3bcaaec706e27b973bb303018002633fd3be7c2ac367d174bafce52e84e?context=explore) when the container runs is just `bash`. To keep your container alive, use the `-t` command of the `docker run` command :

> -t, --tty Allocate a pseudo-TTY

`docker run -t --name test_debian -d debian:bookworm-slim`

If you wish to open a shell within the container and interact with it, use the `-i` option as well.

> -i, --interactive Keep STDIN open even if not attached

`docker run -it --name test_debian -d debian:bookworm-slim`

Don't forget to delete containers between operations as two containers cannot have the same name.